# Override AutoQuery MaxLimit on specifc endpoint

Tags: servicestack

If a max limit is set for autoquery in startup:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100 });
```

Is there anyway to override this on a specific service endpoint where I override autoquery?

I want this enforced for all public endpoints but on admin side I want to be able to get as much data as I like but when I inject AutoQuery object into service I can't see any way to override the limit on the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a [Custom AutoQuery Implementation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) where you can override the SQL Expression AutoQuery generates, e.g:

```
public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    //Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(FindMovies query)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request);
        q.Take(CustomLimit);
        return AutoQuery.Execute(query, q);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you should also be able to override the limit with an [AutoQuery Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#extensibility-with-queryfilters):

```
var autoQuery = new AutoQueryFeature()
    .RegisterQueryFilter<FindMovies, Movie>((q, dto, req) => {
        if (req.GetSession().HasRole(RoleNames.Admin, req.TryResolve<IAuthRepository>())
        {
            q.Take(CustomLimit);
        }
    });

Plugins.Add(autoQuery);
```